# Thread handling problem in Android Junit Test Case

Tags: android

I am implementing a testcase in Android Juint. I am facing problem in
handling threads. After the successful running of a test case, it will
not wait for child thread to be finished. e.g. If one testcase call
some services in server. testcase will successfully send request to a
server, but it will not wait for a response. Because testcase will
start this request in a different Thread. Currently I am using
following code,

```
   currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
   synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
           try {
                              Thread.currentThread().wait();
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                           e.printStackTrace();
                   }
```

After getting response I am using the following code to start the
current thread again.

```
  currentThread.interrupt();
```

I think this is not the good way to do it. There must be a some other
technique to handle this problem properly. Please let me know as soon
as possible if any one knows solution for this.

Thanks,

```
 Vashishta
```

Comment: If you want to wait for the thread to complete, why not use Thread.join()?

Answer (score 0):

In your code the `synchronized` block never blocks (wait for another thread), because you synchronize on `Thread.currentThread()` which is a different object in different threads.

You have so synchronize on an object common to all threads: typically an object that contains shared data. Then you `synchronize{..}` a block od code that manipulates this data.

Comment: Hi 
Still I am not able to find any solution. Please explain briefly..:) 
Thanks...